# How can I test useAutocomplete hook onChange event of material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

This is my code of getting the usage of useAutocomplete hook. I want to test the onChange for code coverage. Is there any way to do it by using a react-testing library.

```
 const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    getListboxProps,
    getOptionProps,
    groupedOptions,
    getClearProps
} = useAutocomplete({
    id: 'use-autocomplete-demo',
    options: routeInformation ? routeInformation : [],
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.routeName,
    clearOnEscape: true,
    disableClearable: false,
    onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, value: any) => {
        if (setPreviousRoute && setSelectedRoute) {
            setPreviousRoute({...selectedRoute} as RouteInformation);
            if ( value ) {
                setSelectedRoute({...value} as RouteInformation);
            } else {
                setSelectedRoute(undefined);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My render element looks like this and the groupedOptions are not having any data when I'm testing from the react-testing-library.

```
<div>
                        <div {...getRootProps()} >
                            <InputBase
                                data-testid="SearchInput"
                                {...getInputProps()}
                                placeholder="Search Route Name"
                                classes={{
                                    root: classes.inputRoot,
                                    input: classes.inputInput,
                                }}
                                endAdornment={
                                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                                        <IconButton  {...getClearProps()}>
                                            <CancelRoundedIcon fontSize="small"/>
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </InputAdornment>
                                }
                                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <ul data-testid="SuggestionsList" className={classes.suggestionContainer} {...getListboxProps()}>
                            {groupedOptions.map((option, index) => (
                                <li className={classes.suggestionItem} {...getOptionProps({ option, index })}>
                                    {option.routeName} | ID: {option.routeId}
                                </li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: do you find a solution please ?